# How do I get specific names from a text file with a location as condition?

Tags: c, string, file

Please help me. I'm new to programming. I've been trying and searching for days to answer this.

I need a C program that will open a text file named users.txt

In that text file there are names then comma and their schools.

```
John Paul, Legit Univ
Paul John, Yo Univ
Lebron James, School Univ
James Lebron, Legit Univ
```

All I managed so far is to display them all. The output should be all the users that are from `"Legit Univ"`.

Sample output:

```
Found 2 users from Legit Univ

John Paul
James Lebron
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you read the file, how do you check if a line matches your criteria? Please edit your question to include your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing how you fail to do your task.

Comment: My program simply prints everything in the textfile. I need it to only print the names  from a specific university.

Comment: That means you understand your assignment. How did you try to filter? How do you read the file, how do you split name and location? Show your code.

Comment: No. My code simply opens the file and prints everything. I have no idea how to filter.

Comment: As this is obviously homework, you need to show some effort. You know the steps: read a line (suggest: use `fgets`), split name/location (use `strchr`), check if location matches (do a string comparison), print. If you do not have an idea for any of these 4 steps, you need to revisit your learning material. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](How do I ask and answer homework questions?)

Comment: I am trying. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: That link should have been [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fgets()` to read a line from file into a string, then `strchr()`  to to find the position of the comma ',' field separator in the string (or `strstr()` if the field separator is comma space ", ").  Now you can check the part of the string after the field separator for a match on your query with `strcmp()`.  Instead of parsing the file, you could also use a regex and match against the string.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to load one line at a time (as you are doing). Then, search the buffer for the target string (like "Legit Univ") using `strstr()`. If found, then go about trimming at the comma (perhaps `strtok()` and outputting the name ( `puts()` ). If not found, move on to the next record (input line).

Don't do more processing than you have to.

The "Found 2 users at Legit Univ" is a bit of a problem, though. Either you can buffer up the names in a linked-list while counting 'hits', OR you could change the output to print the count of 'hits' AFTER the report of the names. (Or, worse, you could process the file once to count, rewind, then output the count AHEAD of the 'user' names...) How stringent are the requirements of the output?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the strings with the following:
`fscanf(<stream_name>,"%[^,] %s",<string_name_1>,<string_name_2> )` here `%[^,]` basically means read until you see a comma and store it in <string_name_1> and store the rest in <string_name_2>. After that, all you need to do is strncmp the <string_name_2> with the name of the university you are searching for, and if the result of strncmp is zero, that means what is written and what you are searching for is the same.